# Bad hdfs permissions with Spark-SQL over yarn-cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple job which is reading in hdfs over hive by spark sql. I started by running it in yarn-client mode and i had not any problem. Since few times, i started to launch it over yarn-cluster mode and i have this problem :

I have this hdfs permission error :

```
Caused by:MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yarn, access=EXECUTE, inode="/Projects/SNB/directory/Private/table/table_ORC":hdfs:mygroup:drwxr-xr--
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getFileInfo(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:3857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:29329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:29306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:29237)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1022)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:997)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:976)
    ... 68 more`
```

But, when i'm doing an hdfs dfs -ls on this directory, it show me this :

```
drwxrwxrwx -lb23598 mygroups 0 2016-12-20 17:58 /Projects/SNB/directory/Private/table/table_ORC
```

So there is like a desynchronization between what yarn is getting and the current permissions set in hdfs.

Do you have an idea about it ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `Permission denied: user=yarn` >> are you running your YARN job as `yarn` system user?!? I thought it was blacklisted, and would not even be allowed to start the job...

Comment: No, i'm running the job as a normal user

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an environment variable as shown below before submitting the job

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=<NAME_OF_THE_USER_THAT_HAS_HDFS_PERMISSION>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your spark driver is being submitted as `yarn` user and the hdfs path that you are trying to access is owned by some other user.

Either changing owner of the hdfs file to `yarn` or submitting spark job as an user same as the owner of the hdfs path should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I understand the error, but i'm running the job as a normal unix user and not as yarn

Comment: Could you tell me HADOOP_USER_NAME environment variable's value? While submitting the job, try setting it to the same user as the owner of the hdfs file.

Comment: How can i know it ? But in fact it is just a part from the problem. I don't get why hdfs permissions are not the same in logs and i nreality

Comment: Could you try changing the hdfs file owner to yarn and see if it works?